# Azure Powershell - rename Database for PostgreSQL Server instance

Tags: postgresql, azure, powershell

We have a **Database for PostgreSql Server** resource in Azure, with
Locally redundant backup option set for Point in Time restoration as needed. 
When restoring - a new server name is specified as part of the process.
Is there a way to rename the Server Name using Azure Powershell, post restore?
If not - is there any other known method to achieve that?

(the reason for asking is to test Disaster Recovery options, without losing original Server Resource, whilst maintaining the same server name)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot rename Database for PostgreSQL Server instance.

Comment: Thanks - yes I am aware of that for SQL databases, but my question is specifically for postgres, so this doesn't answer my question.  Unfortunately - that is the resource type been used in this example.

Comment: @Henry T, As I already said it is not possible to rename Database for PostgreSQL Server instance. You can reach the azure support here-https://twitter.com/AzureSupport